# ios) How to create a suggesion view above the custom keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, custom-keyboard, inputaccessoryview

I'm developing the custom keyboard adding a target moded 'custom keyboard'.

So I'm developing my subclass of UIInputViewController.

I've done to make my custom keyboard type correctly.

So I need to create a suggestion view just above my custom keyboard according to the text the user types so far.

It is the module exactly the same with the one of the default system keyboard.

But When I try to access 'inputAccessoryView' with the code below:

```
let customView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width,100))
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.inputAccessoryView = customView
```

I got an error :

> Cannot assign to property:'iputAccessoryView' is a get-only property

I searched a lot but nothing works with me.

**I found some posts referring `'UITextField'` and `'accessoryview of UITextField'` `not related to 'UIInputViewController'`.**

***But after activating auto completion mode, the default system keyboard shows me the inputAccessoryView full of suggestion keywords but my custom keyboard shows nothing above itself.***

**I think the work should be done in 'UIInputViewController' not with 'UITextField' and the activation is necessary for my custom keyboard to create its inputAccessoryview.**

Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) documentation states:

> "Any class inheriting directly or indirectly from `UIResponder` (usually
>   a custom view) can specify its own input view and input accessory
>   view."

You do need to define your `inputAccessoryView` in a subclass of something like `UIView` or `UITextField` which both inherit from `UIResponder`. By doing that, you define what should show above the keyboard when a specific kind of view becomes the first responder.

You will end up with something like:

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return myView
    }
}
```

When a `MyTextField` becomes first responder, `myView` will be shown above the keyboard.